# Как построить график функции в python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как построить график функции с шагом 0.1 по абсциссе, используя matplotlib?

4sin(πt + π/8) − 1 на отрезке [−10; 10]

Comment: Как и любой другой. С чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: не могу найти теорию

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/matplotlib

Comment: ...Теорию чего?